# How can I style drop-down menus to be as wide as their largest content?

Tags: html, css

I want the menus to keep their size even once the items are hidden. If I use `display:none` on the drop-down items, the menu becomes only as wide as the selected item. So when the items become shown again on hover, if any of the hidden items were wider than the selected item, the menu gets wider which looks bad. But if I only hide them, the drop-down items can still active the hover event, so if you hover over where they're hidden, the drop-down is displayed.

You can see this problem below (view full page):

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300';

body {
  margin:0px;
  color:#25373D;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color:#DAE5E8;
}

#Title {
  width:100vw;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0.1in;
  font-size:0.3in;
}

#Settings {
  background-color:#25373D;
  width:100vw;
  height:0.85in;
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content:center;
}

.dash {
  margin:0.1in 0 0.1in 0;
  position:relative;
  font-size:0.2in;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0.2in;

}

.select-input {
  margin:0.1in;
  position:relative;
  font-size:0.2in;
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.select-input > div {
  visibility:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:0.2in;
  background-color:#040C0F;
  display:flex;
}

.select-input > div:hover {
  visibility:visible;
  background-color:#5E7B85;
}


.select-input:hover > div {
  visibility:visible;
}

.select-input > .selected {
  visibility:visible;
  background-color:#040C0F !important;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Title">Smite Team Guru</div>
<div id="Settings">
  <div class="select-input" id="Mode">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Conquest">Conquest</div>
    <div data-value="Joust">Joust</div>
    <div data-value="Arena">Arena</div>
    <div data-value="Clash">Clash</div>
    <div data-value="Siege">Siege</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Type">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Casual">Casual</div>
    <div data-value="Ranked">Ranked</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Min-Rank">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Qualifying">Qualifying</div>
    <div data-value="Bronze">Bronze</div>
    <div data-value="Silver">Silver</div>
    <div data-value="Gold">Gold</div>
    <div data-value="Platinum">Platinum</div>
    <div data-value="Diamond">Diamond</div>
    <div data-value="Grand Master">Master</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dash">-</div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Max-Rank">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Grand Master">Master</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">Qualifying</div>
    <div data-value="Bronze">Bronze</div>
    <div data-value="Silver">Silver</div>
    <div data-value="Gold">Gold</div>
    <div data-value="Platinum">Platinum</div>
    <div data-value="Diamond">Diamond</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Time-Span">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Qualifying">1 Week</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2 Weeks</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">1 Month</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">3 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">6 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2000 B.C.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What's the cleanest way I can do this properly with pure CSS? If we could use logic in css like

```
if (.selected:hover) .select-input > div { visibility:auto };
```

then that'd be great, but I don't know of any selectors that achieve that kind of selection logic.

Comment: I'm getting "The owner of this Pen needs to verify their email address to enable Full Page View" message when trying to view in Codepen's Full View...

Comment: @robjez Fixed that.

Comment: Post an answer, so it might help someone with similar problem in the future

Comment: @robjez No, I mean I fixed the Codepen Full View error.

Comment: @Vizionary :) I can see the problem now, and understand that it was hard to verbalise it.

Comment: @robjez yes it was :/ Btw if you can verbalize it better feel free to replace my first paragraph, Ill accept an edit which improves clarity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your **.select-input** 's height to 0 , and it gonna match what you hope.

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300';

body {
  margin:0px;
  color:#25373D;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color:#DAE5E8;
}

#Title {
  width:100vw;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0.1in;
  font-size:0.3in;
}

#Settings {
  background-color:#25373D;
  width:100vw;
  height:0.85in;
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content:center;
}

.dash {
  margin:0.1in 0 0.1in 0;
  position:relative;
  font-size:0.2in;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0.2in;

}

.select-input {
  height:0;
  margin:0.1in;
  position:relative;
  font-size:0.2in;
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.select-input > div {
  visibility:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:0.2in;
  background-color:#040C0F;
  display:flex;
}

.select-input > div:hover {
  visibility:visible;
  background-color:#5E7B85;
}


.select-input:hover >div {
  visibility:visible;
}

.select-input > .selected {
  visibility:visible;
  background-color:#040C0F !important;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Title">Smite Team Guru</div>
<div id="Settings">
  <div class="select-input" id="Mode">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Conquest">Conquest</div>
    <div data-value="Joust">Joust</div>
    <div data-value="Arena">Arena</div>
    <div data-value="Clash">Clash</div>
    <div data-value="Siege">Siege</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Type">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Casual">Casual</div>
    <div data-value="Ranked">Ranked</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Min-Rank">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Qualifying">Qualifying</div>
    <div data-value="Bronze">Bronze</div>
    <div data-value="Silver">Silver</div>
    <div data-value="Gold">Gold</div>
    <div data-value="Platinum">Platinum</div>
    <div data-value="Diamond">Diamond</div>
    <div data-value="Grand Master">Master</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dash">-</div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Max-Rank">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Grand Master">Master</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">Qualifying</div>
    <div data-value="Bronze">Bronze</div>
    <div data-value="Silver">Silver</div>
    <div data-value="Gold">Gold</div>
    <div data-value="Platinum">Platinum</div>
    <div data-value="Diamond">Diamond</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Time-Span">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Qualifying">1 Week</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2 Weeks</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">1 Month</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">3 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">6 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2000 B.C.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: brilliant. Why is the solution always so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that using visibility: hidden only hides the div whilst still allocating it space on the page. Its better to use display: none and then set the display on hover.

Try this [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWbmEp)

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300';

body {
  margin:0px;
  color:#25373D;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color:#DAE5E8;
}

#Title {
  width:100vw;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0.1in;
  font-size:0.3in;
}

#Settings {
  background-color:#25373D;
  width:100vw;
  height:0.85in;
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content:center;
}

.dash {
  margin:0.1in 0 0.1in 0;
  position:relative;
  font-size:0.2in;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0.2in;

}

.select-input {
  margin:0.1in;
  position:relative;
  font-size:0.2in;
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.select-input > div {
  display: none;
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:0.2in;
  background-color:#040C0F;
}

.select-input > div:hover {
  visibility:visible;
  background-color:#5E7B85;
}


.select-input:hover > div {
    display:flex;
  visibility:visible;
}

.select-input > .selected {
  display:flex;
  visibility:visible;
  background-color:#040C0F !important;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Title">Smite Team Guru</div>
<div id="Settings">
  <div class="select-input" id="Mode">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Conquest">Conquest</div>
    <div data-value="Joust">Joust</div>
    <div data-value="Arena">Arena</div>
    <div data-value="Clash">Clash</div>
    <div data-value="Siege">Siege</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Type">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Casual">Casual</div>
    <div data-value="Ranked">Ranked</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Min-Rank">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Qualifying">Qualifying</div>
    <div data-value="Bronze">Bronze</div>
    <div data-value="Silver">Silver</div>
    <div data-value="Gold">Gold</div>
    <div data-value="Platinum">Platinum</div>
    <div data-value="Diamond">Diamond</div>
    <div data-value="Grand Master">Master</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dash">-</div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Max-Rank">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Grand Master">Master</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">Qualifying</div>
    <div data-value="Bronze">Bronze</div>
    <div data-value="Silver">Silver</div>
    <div data-value="Gold">Gold</div>
    <div data-value="Platinum">Platinum</div>
    <div data-value="Diamond">Diamond</div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-input" id="Time-Span">
    <div class="selected" data-value="Qualifying">1 Week</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2 Weeks</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">1 Month</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">3 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">6 Months</div>
    <div data-value="Qualifying">2000 B.C.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You basically just did what I said was the problem. When you do it this way, the menu changes size when the wider elements are no longer displayed. "Qualifying" is longer than "Master" so when the menu is hovered, it gets wider to fit "Qualifying". That looks bad, and that's my whole problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Then why can't you explicitly state the width of the menu divs?

Comment: Because I want them to fit the width of the largest content, not a static width.

Answer (score 0):

my advice is to try with  with

. I dn, maybe my answer could be of any help.

```css
.nav ul{list-style: none;}
.nav ul li{float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; position: relative;}
.nav ul a{display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 39px; text-decoration: none; color: #e8b400;}
.nav li > ul{display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 2;top: 100%; left: 0px; border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;}
.nav li:hover > ul{display: block; background-color: #9f6900;}
.nav li > ul > li {width: 150px; height: 40px;}
.nav li > ul > li > ul{left: 100%; top:0px; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;}
.nav li > ul > li > ul > li{width: 100px;}
.nav li:hover > a{color: #e4c300;}
```